# Existence of a coproduct and representability of a functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I've found this claim:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category; the family $\lbrace C_i \rbrace_{i \in I }$ has a coproduct in $\mathcal{C}$ if and only if the functor $$F : \mathcal{C} \to Set$$ $$A \mapsto \bigcup_{i \in I } \hom(C_i , A )$$ is representable.

Is it right ? Why there isn't the functor $$A \mapsto \prod_{i \in I} \hom(C_i, A )\ ?$$

Comment: Your claim is the correct version.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Do you mean the version  that I found or the last ?

Comment: The claim as stated is wrong. Your version of the claim is correct.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: ok thanks

Comment: Please turn your comments into answers so that the question is "officially" answered.